POST запрос к API WB ошибка invalid payload body
Отправляю POST запрос к WB на получения статистики рекламных компаний и получаю ответ: {"error":"Invalid Params: invalid payload body"}
Делал POST запросы к другим отчетам, всё ок.
Единственная разница в описании API это передача в payload {} и [].
И получается там где параметры передаются в качестве объекта, всё ок, а с массивом не работает
Код запроса
var options = {
      method: 'post',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      headers: {
          'Authorization': apiKey,
          'accept': 'application/json',
          'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      },
      
      payload: JSON.stringify([
        {'id':19539663, 'dates':[2024-10-30, 2024-10-30]}
      ])
  };
try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl, options);
    Logger.log('responseData : '+response);
} catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Ошибка при выполнении запроса: ' + error);
}

Описание API
Request Body schema: application/json
required
Array ([ 1 .. 100 ] items) [
    id          integer
    ID кампании

    dates           Array of strings <date> [ items <date > ]
    Даты, за которые необходимо выдать информацию.
]

и пример из описания:
[
    {
    "id": 8960367,
    "dates": []
    },
    {
    "id": 9876543,
    "dates": []
    }
]

Опять не могу разобраться что не так :(

Попробуйте такие элементы 2024-10-30 поместить в апострофы или кавычки. Тем более в документации прописано Array of strings <date>

Вы правы, это помогло. Даже писать стыдно.

Ничего страшного, все мы можем ошибаться в простых вещах, создавая сложные)
